# Which STD container to use to get [] operator and erase elements without moving memory around?

Tags: c++, stl

I used `std::vector<MyClass>` and everything was fine until I had to use `erase()` function. Problem caused by `MyClass` having

```
MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
```

This is needed because `MyClass` holds `unique_ptr` objects and I generally want to avoid copy. But at this point my code has index access [] operator utilized, and I dont want to re write chucks of code. Is there a container in STD that is suitable?

Edit:

To people suggesting usage of move constructor, I've tried this:

```
//MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
//MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
MyClass(MyClass&&) = default;
```

but compiler(g++) still gives error:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:405:25: error: use of deleted function ‘M::MyClass& M::MyClass::operator=(const M::MyClass&)’
  405 |               *__result = std::move(*__first);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

saying:

```
note: ‘M::MyClass& M::MyClass::operator=(const M::MyClass&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘M::MyClass’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
```

or I should not use `default` keyword and actually define move constructor?

Comment: It'd be easy to write a wrapper for `std::list` and add `operator[]` to that but lookup using indexing would be costly.

Comment: Make your class moveable, that's the only requirement for `erase()` and `unique_ptr` is moveable.

Comment: Alternatively, what about making your class movable? If you just remove your copy constructor declarations, the `std::unique_ptr` members will let the compiler generate a move constructor but no copy constructor. Although make sure not to keep references to the moved objects.

Comment: Use move assignment / constructor?

Comment: About your added error, it looks like you're trying to move from a `const` object somewhere (which actually tries to copy it).

Comment: Can you please post a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: If your class has a `std::unique_ptr<T>` member, then you don't need to define copy or move semantics. The object is implicitly non-copyable and movable by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a moveable and non-copyable type, any class with a `std::unique_ptr<T>` member will by default be moveable and non-copyable (as long as all of the other members are at least moveable).

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct A {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    //A b = a; //Will not compile
    A c = std::move(a); // Perfectly legal
}
```

Therefore if you remove the copy contstructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, and move assignment operator, then everything would work fine. Your type would not be copyable, and erasing from `std::vector` would work fine.

Note: `std::vector<T>::operator[]` returns a reference to the element so no copy is performed at this step either (for `T` not equal to `bool`).

If you want to explicitly `= delete` the copy semantics then you also have to `= default` both the move constructor and move assignment operator to keep the move semantics of the type. This is known as [the rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: That worked. I've added default move assignment operator(but had to remove const keyword from all class members) and program compiled. Can live without const I guess because that was only a hint for compiler for optimizations.